# Does macro function with operator precedence show unusual result?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

```
#define SQUARE(x,y) (x<y?x:y)
   int a = 5, b = 6, c = 3;
    int var = SQUARE(a & c,b);
```

I have searched and learnt that '<' precede '&'. As per rules it should give '5'. But it is giving output as '1'. But in some cases it is giving right output. Can you please explain macro rules of this and what am I missing here.

Comment: there are no "macro functions", only "function-like macros" -- you just found the difference. A macro is always just replacing text in your source code, even if it looks like a function.

Comment: apart from the precedence issue you're getting here, things can get worse when parameters have *side-effects* when evaluated. Your macro will evaluate both `x` and `y` **twice** ... a function call wouldn't.

Comment: Anyway, why are you calling it `SQUARE`?

Comment: It is just a function name nothing else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macros are just replaced by the preprocessor, so the arguments are not evaluated and then passed like in functions.

In your example the expression `SQUARE(a & c, b);` will become `(a & c < b ? a & c : b);`

For `a=5, b=6, c=3` it evaluates to:

```
(5 & 3<6 ? 5&3 : 6) //'<' precede '&' as you correctly mentioned
(5&1 ? 5&3 : 6) // '3 < 6' is a boolean expression which evaluates to 1. '&' is bitwise AND.
(1 ? 1 : 6)
(1)
```

So `1` is the right output.

EDIT:

A good aproach is to always use parentheses around your arguments and the whole expression to eliminate the problem of operator precedence.

As mention by others it can be dangerous to use macros due to multiple evaluation, which may not only effect performance.

For example:

```
#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))
```

seems to only square the argument, but if you call it like

```
f = SQUARE(x++);
```

you will get undefined behaviour. A better approach for small function would be to declare it as `inline`.

```
inline int square(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Also as mentioned by @EricPostpischil macros are not a textual replacement as the preprocessor replaces by tokens.

For example:

```
#define a 1
#define b 2

printf("%d\n", ab);
```

here `ab` is not replaced with `12` as someone would expect for pure textual replacement.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was missing, replacing the variable with the sent values. And if you give me any link or something to know more about Macros as their output is different to others with some explanation please.

Comment: '#define foo(x, y) (x / y + x)
    int i = -6, j = 3;
    printf("%d\n",foo(i + j, 3));'  
Can you please explain this, Output is '-8'

Comment: @Taufiq The macro evaluates to `(-6+3 / 3 + -6+3)`, which becomes `(-6+1-6+3)` which is `-8`. Note that `/` binds stronger than `+`.

Answer (score 3):

Macros require parentheses as they are not functions and just do the textual replacement

```
#define SQUARE(x,y) (((x)<(y))?(x):(y))
```

The macro is extremely side effects error and UB prone:

Example: `SQUATE(x++,y)`

in your example 5 & 3 will be evaluated every time you have the `x` in your macro. It will be less effective than the inline function

```
inline unsigned SQUARE(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
  return (x < y) ? x : y;
}
```

Comment: Also warn the OP about multiple evaluation

Comment: @chqrlie It is obvious, I think, if the text is just replaced :)

Comment: If all obvious things were equally obvious for everyone, there wouldn't be questions...

Comment: The macro `SQUARE` obviously computes the minimum value of its arguments, and the inline function does it using `unsigned` arithmetic, which is questionable given the type of `a`, `b`, `c` and `var` in the OP's code...

Comment: Macros do replacement by preprocessor tokens, not text.

Comment: @EricPostpischil in this case === text

Comment: @P__J__: Teaching people a false rule leads them to incorrect conclusions in the future. The fact that the rule’s error is not apparent in the current instance is not redeeming and may even make it worse, as it leads people to believe the false rule is correct, which hinders their ability to discover errors in the future.

Comment: @EricPostpischil preprocessor tokenisation is far beyond the scope of this question and is usually confusing for the beginners (and I think OP is one of). Most beginners books simplifies it to the textual replacement as well.

Comment: (a) Tokenization is not beyond the scope of the question; it is fundamental to macro expansion. (b) Confusion for beginners is grounds for explaining carefully and in appropriate steps. It is not grounds for making false statements. One could say the replacement is similar to replacing macro with the source code from the macro, or even say it is similar to text replacement but caution the reader that it is not exactly text replacement. (c) Why should anybody accept unnamed beginners books as a good example?

Comment: So try to use this language teaching beginners :) The effect will right oppsite than expected. They just will not understand anything and will have total mess in their heads. That is the reason why people start learning in the primary school, not at the  uni

Answer (score 1):

In a bit more detail, as @P__J__ said, macros are just text replacement by the pre-processor, not functions. So this:

```
#define SQUARE(x,y) (x<y?x:y)
int a = 5, b = 6, c = 3;
int var = SQUARE(a & c,b);
```

is translated to:

```
int a = 5, b = 6, c = 3;
int var = (a & c<b?a & c:b);
```

Because every `x` is replaced with `a & c` and every y is replaced with `b`.

If you also apply the values as in @Osiris 's answer, you'll get:

```
int var = (5 & 3 < 6 ? 5 & 3 : 6);
```

At this point, as you already said, `<` takes precedence over `&`.

The result of `<` is true or false, which means `1` or `0`, so `3 < 6` becomes `1`.

The result of `&` is the bitwise `AND` between two numbers, which in this case is also `1` (because `5` is `101` and `3` is `011`).

This is why it becomes

`(5 & 1 ? 1 : 6)`

That next `5 & 1` will also become `1` (because of the `AND` between `101` and `001`), so you'll get:

`(1 ? 1 : 6)`

And since `1` is true, you'll get the first value, which is also a `1`.

Also, as already pointed out, be careful with evaluation in a macro.
These are just numbers and you're already seeing some not so obvious behaviour, but if had passed a function as one of the arguments, that function would've run multiple times.

For example

```
#define SQUARE(x,y) (x<y?x:y)
int var = SQUARE(update_counter(a), 1);
```

would have been translated to

```
int var = (update_counter(a) < 1 ? update_counter(a) : 1);
```

Thus potentially updating a hypothetical counter twice.

Comment: Macros do replacement by preprocessor tokens, not text.